# HTTP Apis for MT4

Tags: python, zeromq, metatrader4, mt4

I'm exploring options to create RESTful APIs for MT4 without setting up EA. As an example, http://mt4.mtapi.be/index.html - is just what I want to create.

However, the problem is that I'm not entirely sure if its possible to do so without setting up EA inside the MT4 terminal.
I read this [post](https://www.mql5.com/en/blogs/post/716643) and it seems like ZeroMQ can be used.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me.

I have set up a Google Apps Script (bound to a spreadsheet) that's connecting to the Oanda API.
Maybe that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks. I checked Oanda's api documentation on MT4 but couldn't find it, unfortunately. Please can you share the link as well?

Comment: Start here: https://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/introduction/ Then use Google Apps Script (JavaScript-alike) and with its UrlFetchApp make a call to OANDA's REST server, providing your acces token as mentioned on their introduction page.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Checked the docs however this seems restricted to OANDA only accounts. What if I have an account with a different broker?

Comment: I don't know. If they host a MT4 interface, it might work. Please update here if you succeed.